# Procedimiento almacenado desde una Open Query usando PYODBC

Tags: sql, informix, pyodbc

Estoy trabajando con PYODBC en Jupyter y quiero llamar a un procedimiento almacenado desde una openquery con un linked-server (desde sql-server a informix) pero cuando ejecuto la cadena de la consulta, me arroja un error porque no reconoce los parámetros. Mi conexión ODBC apunt al servidor de sql

¿Cómo puedo hacer esta tarea? Intento usar el atributo params en la ejecución de pandas, como:

```py
pd.read_sql(sql_str, con=cnxn, params=['value1', 'value2'])
```

con el símbolo "?" dentro de los parámetros en la cadena de la consulta pero no funcionó

Ejemplo:

```py
sql_str = "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linked_server, 'execute procedure my_sp_in_informix(input_param_1, input_param_2))"
```